# How to describe line items in Stripe checkout?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

This is the way how I create checkout function:

```php
foreach($request->arrayOfObjects as $req) {
    array_push($lineItems, [
        'price' => $req['priceID'],
        'quantity' => (int) $req['quantity']
    ]);
}
    
if (Auth::check()) {
    $charge = $stripeClient->checkout->sessions->create([
        'payment_method_types' => [
            'card',
            'sepa_debit',
            'giropay',
            'sofort',
            'alipay'
        ],
        'success_url' => env('APP_URL').'/success',
        'cancel_url' => env('APP_URL').'/cancel',
        'shipping_address_collection' => [
            'allowed_countries' => ['DE'],
        ],
        'shipping_options' => [
            [
               'shipping_rate' => $request->lieferung ? env('SHIPPING_RATE_LIEFERUNG') : env('SHIPPING_RATE_ABHOLUNG')
            ],
        ],
        'line_items' => [$lineItems],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'metadata' => [
            'lieferung' => $request->lieferung,
            'isCustomer' => true
        ],
        'allow_promotion_codes' => true,
        'customer' => Auth::user()->stripe_id
    ]);
}
```

It works fine though... However, I'd like to know is there way to describe measurements of an article?

For example I have ordered 10 packages of Parquet Flooring Classic and each package has 3m2 of parquet.

I'd like to see it in the bill, like:

> Article 1001 - Parquet Flooring Classic (10x Packages - 3m2 each)

I found that metadata could be provided but only for the global checkout level, not per item.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** provide metadata per item using Stripe Checkout. Here's an example:

```php
$charge = $stripeClient->checkout->sessions->create([
    ...
    'line_items' => [
        // item 1
        [
            'price_data' => [
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Item A',
                ],
                // 10.99 USD
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'unit_amount' => 1099,
            ],
            'quantity' => 3,
        ],
        // item 2
        [
            'price_data' => [
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Item B',
                ],
                // 5.49 USD
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'unit_amount' => 549,
            ],
            'quantity' => 2, 
        ],
    ],
    ...
]);
```

At checkout, it will give you a neat list of

```
3 x Item A ....... 32.97 $ USD
2 x Item B ....... 10.98 $ USD
```

Check all the information on line_items in [The stripe API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) (click on the 'show child attributes' button for all the possible keys and what they're for.)

Comment: Where do you provide metadata per item? I need to describe what `3x` means. For example, it is not same case if I have `3x Parquet Flooring` and `3x Hammer` ... For Hammer it is clear because it is per item, but not for Parquet because package size can vary. It could be 5x 2.1 m2 or 5x 3 m2.

Comment: You can put that in `product_data.name`. It's arbitrary. `quantity` is how many units they're buying, and then just add all off that info in product data `name`. For example. `'quantity' => 10` and `'product_data' => ['name' => 'Parquet Flooring Classic 3m2 each']`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help! I was trying to simplify it using productID and priceID. Using those it is not possible to achieve what I need.